# sorting list in python based on dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which I have gotten from json.loads();

```
myList = [{'label': 'Users', 'host': 'XYZ', 'tags': {'customer': 'XYZ'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}, 
          {'label': 'Users', 'host': 'ABC', 'tags': {'customer': 'ABC'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}, 
          {'label': 'Users', 'host': 'EFG', 'tags': {'customer': 'EFG'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}]
```

Is there a way to sort this list based of `host` key so that it becomes like this?

```
mySortedList = [{'label': 'Users', 'host': 'ABC', 'tags': {'customer': 'ABC'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}, 
                {'label': 'Users', 'host': 'EFG', 'tags': {'customer': 'EFG'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}, 
                {'label': 'Users', 'host': 'XYZ', 'tags': {'customer': 'XYZ'}, 'data': [[1518756360, 1]]}]
```

I tried `myList.sort()` and `myList.sort(key='host')` but it didn't work.

Comment: `key=itemgetter('host')`

Comment: Doing research (search SO/google/Apis) should come before posting a question - see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This avoids having the same (or similar) questions over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

With `sorted` you can determine after what you want to sort with a lambda function.
In your case `sorted(myList, key=lambda k: k['host'])`.

Or without lambda (as pointed out by @padraic-cunningham and @arount):

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(myList, key=itemgetter('host'))
```

Comment: No lambda needed here. As @padraic-cunningham pointed in comments you can just specify what key you want to use as sorting index